# how to add :hover on my class .active when my window scroll be >50

Tags: jquery, html, css

i need add :hover when the class .active be added with my function scrollTop() > 50, because when this happened my class a:hover is removed.

https://codepen.io/ta_io/pen/QRgEJw

```
.logo a {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 36px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  outline: none;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 36px;
}

nav ul li a.active {
  color: coral;
}
.logo a.active {
  color: coral;
}


$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
    $("nav ul li a").addClass("active");
  } else {
    $("nav ul li a").removeClass("active");
  }
});

$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
    $(".logo a").addClass("active");
  } else {
    $(".logo a").removeClass("active");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the issue is the hover effect no longer works once the styles change on scroll. Updated styles for your CSS below. Added hover states for the .active a tags.

```
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 auto;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 auto;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 85%;
  height: 80px;
}

.logo {
  font-family: "at";
}

a {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 36px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color 0.6s ease;
}
a:hover {
  color: #ccc;
}
ul {
  font-family: "at";

  display: block;
  list-style-type: disc;
  margin-block-start: 0em;
  margin-block-end: 0em;
  margin-inline-start: 0px;
  margin-inline-end: 0px;
  padding-inline-start: 0px;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "at";
  margin-top: 0px;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  outline: none;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 36px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 85%;
  height: 76px;
  background-color: aqua;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.content-wrapper {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 85%;
  height: 2000px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: dimgray;
}
nav ul li a.active, .logo a.active {
  color: coral;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
}

nav ul li a.active:hover, .logo a.active:hover {
  color: #ccc;
}
```